# Prevent users from pushing all tags to a Bitbucket repository

Tags: git, tags, bitbucket, push, restriction

I have a repository where I routinely remove old tags that are no longer needed or at the heads of branches that have since been rebased. Sometimes a developer in our team will push to git using the command `git push --tags` which will push all of the tags that were pruned back onto origin. We encourage our developers to specify the tag they would like to push instead of using --tags but mistakes happen and sometimes we get all our old tags appearing again.

So firstly, I would like to know if this is even possible in Bitbucket and if not, is there a work around that would provide the same restriction?

The issue is only happening when a human uses the wrong command by mistake, so it doesn't need to completely block if there is a solution that would warn or need to be implemented per user instead, although a centralised rule would be preferred.

I googled for an answer to this and found this link https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-do-i-block-all-tags-from-being-pushed-to-a-repository-822021700.html however while testing this solution I found some problems:

1. The Bitbucket interface has changed somewhat since then and when trying to create a branch pattern of `/refs/tags/**` I get the error message `Consecutive wildcard characters are not allowed`
2. When trying with the branch pattern of `/refs/tags/*` (which is allowed), it still allows me to push all tags using `git push --tags` which is not the desired outcome.
3. Even if this did work, I think it would prevent any tag from being pushed rather than only pushes that included multiple tags.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a specific way to do it with Bitbucket, but here is a pre-receive Git hook that will refuse a push with more than 1 tag.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

tag_count=0

while read ref_infos
do
    eval "ref_name=`echo $ref_infos | cut -d' ' -f3`"
    case $ref_name in ('refs/tags/'*)
        # Only increment the tag count for created/updated tags, not deleted ones
        eval "ref_target=`echo $ref_infos | cut -d' ' -f2`"
        if test $ref_target != '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'; then
            tag_count=$((tag_count + 1))
        fi
    esac
    if test $tag_count -gt 1; then
        echo 'You are trying to push more than 1 tag at once, which is forbidden.'
        echo 'Please push your tags one by one, and ensure they are relevant to the remote.'
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

For a self-hosted Bitbucket instance, your repository pre-receive hooks should be somewhere in:

```
<installation-path>/Bitbucket/shared/data/repositories/<ID>/hooks/pre-receive.d/
```

After some googling, I found [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-to-create-a-simple-hook-in-bitbucket-server-779171711.html) about hooks on Bitbucket.

Using the Java plugin framework, you should be able to do it even on the Cloud version of Bitbucket, but is also means you have to develop a plugin for this, like [in this example](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/docs/4.7.1/how-tos/repo-hook-examples/pre-receive-branch-config.html), which is way more tedious.

If you prefer, you can use the same code client-side as a pre-push Git hook.
The path of the hooks is `<repository-path>/.git/hooks/`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this out next week. Git hooks seems like the way